# CMD batch ren according to specific list including subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename

it has been years for me to use cmd and I cannot remember a thing. Now I am stuck trying to batch rename a long list of directories and subdirectories according to a specific list.

What I have here is a [long] list of set folder and subfolder names (just as an example, may include files in said folders, as well)

```
ren "Folder\S F 1\S F 1.1" "Folder\SF 1\SF 1.1"
ren "Folder\S F 1\S F 1.2" "Folder\SF 1\SF 1.2"
ren "Folder\S F 1\S F 1.3" "Folder\SF 1\SF 1.3"
ren "Folder\S F 1\S F 1.4" "Folder\SF 1\SF 1.4"
```

The ren command only works in the present directory, so this creates a syntax error.

I tried using the "ren" command with a list of specific file and directory names. This resulted in syntax error since the "ren" command only calls the current directory without subdirectories.

Comment: The syntax error is caused by the target filename being a FILENAME. The source name may have a path, but the new name must be a filename alone, ie `ren "Folder\S F 1\S F 1.1" "some new name"` Since you are attempting to `move` the file from one directory to another, you need to use `move`, not `ren`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command **REN** does not support the new file/folder name with path as explained by the usage help output on running `ren /?` in a command prompt window.

It is also not possible to rename `S F 1` to `SF 1` and its subfolder `S F 1.1` to `SF 1.1` with just one execution of command **REN**.

There must be used nested **FOR** loops to rename all the folders to get the wanted folder names.

A simple solution would be:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /D %%G in ("Folder\? ? *") do (
    for /D %%H in ("%%G\? ? *") do for /F "tokens=1*" %%I in ("%%~nxH") do ren "%%H" "%%I%%J"
    for /F "tokens=1*" %%I in ("%%~nxG") do ren "%%G" "%%I%%J"
)
endlocal
```

This code renames first the subfolders in folder `S F 1` and then the folder `S F 1`. The code is very fast but has the disadvantage of not being fail-safe as folders to rename could be skipped by chance or folders are renamed which should not be renamed because of the wildcard pattern matched more folder names as it looks like.

A better code for this folders renaming task is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "BaseFolder=Folder"
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir "%BaseFolder%\? ? *.*" /AD-L /B /S 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"\\. . [0123456789][0123456789]*\.[0123456789][0123456789]*$"') do for /F "tokens=1*" %%I in ("%%~nxG") do ren "%%G" "%%I%%J"
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir "%BaseFolder%\? ? *" /AD-L /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"^. . [0123456789][0123456789]*$"') do for /F "tokens=1*" %%I in ("%%~nxG") do ren "%BaseFolder%\%%G" "%%I%%J"
endlocal
```

The name of the folders found by the two **DIR** commands are verified with **FINDSTR** using a regular expression to make sure to rename only folders with expected naming scheme. Folders with a name not matched by the regular expression are filtered out by **FINDSTR**.

No folder is skipped anymore by chance by this code because of `cmd.exe` processing the batch file gets in this case first all names of the folders to rename loaded into memory before starting the folder renaming process for the subfolders ending with two numbers and a dot between (lowest folder level) and when finished for the folders ending with just one number (last but one folder level).

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on the two **FOR** command lines to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes these two command lines before executing most outer command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with **DIR** and **FINDSTR** with using a separate command process started in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line within `'` appended as additional arguments.